# How to get the enum value for dropdownlist? Currently both text and value are the same

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using C# MVC. I have this model and enum

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male, Female, Others
}
```

Let's say I want to filter my enum, I have this in my controller action method

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {            
        var roles = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Gender))
                         .Where(f => f != Gender.Others.ToString())
                         .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = f, Text = f }).ToList();

        ViewBag.Roles = roles;
        return View();
    }
```

and in my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Roles", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But the problem is the dropdownlist render is

```
<select class="form-control" id="Roles" name="Roles"><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
```

What I want is

```
<select class="form-control" id="Roles" name="Roles"><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option></select>
```

How to get the enum value for dropdownlist? Currently both text and value are the same.

Comment: just retype... Value = (int) f. Values are same because Value = f call ToString method on render.

Comment: @daremachine i tried but it says 'cannot convert type string to int'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need retype to int and then retype to string. Because..
- you are using `Enum.GetNames` which return string values instead of int.
- parse name into enum value and retype to int and then to string because SelectListItem.Value need string as value.

So you need something like this

```
var roles = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Gender))
                .Where(f => f != Gender.Others.ToString())
                .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = ((int) Enum.Parse<Gender>(f)).ToString(), Text = f }).ToList();
```

Option two

You can use `GetValues` instead of `GetNames`

```
var roles2 = ((Gender[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))).ToList()
                .Where(f => f.ToString() != Gender.Others.ToString())
                .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = ((int) f).ToString(), Text = f.ToString() }).ToList();
```

PS: I don't know what is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your enum as below:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male=1, Female=2, Others=3
}
```

Now modify the filter values

Comment: but how to modify?